# bootstrap grid system with table cells

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a responsive `table` with three rows and where each row has
three `td`. Now I want that on small device (< 768px) the text into
second `td` is wrapped down if too long.

I write this code on http://www.bootply.com/n17ZZ17gWd# but when I run it on mobile preview the long text is put always on one line while on full screen preview the long text is wrapped down.

I used into each `td` this: `class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1` but maybe
I misunderstood how to use col-* into `td` and which is it effect?

In practice If I have 3 `td` and I write something like:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-1"> ... </td>
    <td class="col-xs-1"> ... </td> 
    <td class="col-xs-1"> ... </td>
</tr>
```

how can we read `col-xs-1`?

maybe that every `td` span into 1 column and the `tr` still have 9 columns of space?

***or***

that every `td` span into 1 column but each `td` still have 11 columns of space?

Comment: It's an interesting scenario you have going on, please update if you find desired solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** exactly what you asked for, but [**see**](http://www.bootply.com/xpNnLiJRj1) if it gives you any clues.

```
col-xs-1 col-md-2
col-xs-12 col-md-8
col-xs-1 col-md-2
```

It is OK to do it this way for xs, if number of columns exceeds 12, bootstrap will automatically assign it to the separate row.

Comment: Interesting solution (+1) but I have to necessarily use tables because they are generated automatically. About my consideration on using col-* on td what do you think?

Comment: I honestly dont think its even possible to roll that `td` over to the next row. Its kinda violates the whole 'principal' of the table - that's exactly the difference between tables and grids.